# Simultaneous SSH and monitor

Tags: display, setup, pi-b+

Can I SSH into my Pi and have a monitor reflect the activity?

Is there a way to force a refresh of the monitor via SSH?

My setup doesn't include a keyboard so SSH is my current option.

Comment: I've written a small program which connects your ssh connection to the console, so you can ssh into the RPi, and then control the display directly.   https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon

Answer (score 1):

You can use `script` to do so. Script will write (or append) your terminal session into a file.

You can append it to the tty that is being displayed in your monitor.

In *RaspBSD* you can do:

`# script -a -F /dev/ttyv0` and it works flawlessly.

I guess the default `tty` will change between different distributions, so you should look which one is the default in your system (it is listed under /dev/ttysomething)

> The **script** utility makes a typescript of everything printed on your
>        terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an
>        interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can
>        be printed out later with **lpr(1)**.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `screen` (`sudo apt-get install screen`) you can open a command line on the graphical interface, then type `screen` and it will open a normal looking command line. Then from SSH you can `screen -x` which will attach the previous screen. To leave the screen, you press `ctrl + a` then `d` for disconnect.

Here is a pretty helpful page for random information: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Are you sure a screen session can be attached to two terminals simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. That is what the -x is for. From the man (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) `‘-x’
Attach to a session which is already attached elsewhere (multi-display mode). Screen refuses to attach from within itself. But when cascading multiple screens, loops are not detected; take care. `

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could use [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) to forward input from your USB keyboard and mouse to another computer (usbip server) to your RPi (usbip client) over the network. That way you'll be able to use those keyboard and mouse as if they were connected to your RPi, instead of using SSH.

Another similar project is [netevent](https://github.com/Blub/netevent/wiki/Share-devices-over-the-net), which is dedicated to sharing of input devices, as opposed to usbip which shares any USB devices (drives, webcams, etc.) There's also [`barrier`](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier).

There's also [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/67659/linux-share-keyboard-over-network) which lists a few alternative solutions: x2x, Synergy and evdev+netcat.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell the syslog daemon (on Raspbian the package [rsyslog](https://packages.debian.org/rsyslog) is used by default) to write according log messages also to `/dev/console` which is the currently active text console under Linux. (This assumes that no X is running. If you have X running, there is a tool called `xconsole` in the package [x11-apps](https://packages.debian.org/x11-apps) which shows these messages in an X window.)

Additionally you might need to either disable screen blanking permanently (may damage your screen) or make the screen unblank in case of such an event.

The commands to control screen blanking are `xset` under X and the `setterm` on the Linux text consoles.

I though do not know how to trigger a command if a specific message is written to the syslog. One solution might be to also pipe these log messages into a script which checks every input line for the according messages and calls the above mentioned commands if a match is found.